# Android writing on Bitmap with canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-edittext

How do I make my editText what is written in, get written on the Bitmap
I found this code, but it doesn't work

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWrite);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500,Bitmap.Config.Alpha_8);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
et.draw(c);
```

I think I should use currentBitmap I think, I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: What exactly are trying to do? yugidroid code should work but why do need to draw it again using the canvas?

Comment: I'm trying to let the text I typed in the EditText gets written on the pic .. it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like I show you blow:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWrite);
et.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(et.getDrawingCache());
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
et.draw(c);
```

Hope it works!

Comment: maybe cause it's making a new Bitmap ?
can't u make it writes on the currentBitmap ? or choosenBitmap ?

Answer (score 1):

`Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8` only draws the alpha channel. Use `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be enough to put the generated bitmap to a view.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWrite);
et.buildDrawingCache(); 
Bitmap bitmap = et.getDrawingCache();
```

Now use the following line for a normal view

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
```

for imageview use

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
```

AFAIK the draw method will overwrite the pixel values of the bitmap you pass to it using the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this might be a bit late, but basically, you need to use these calls to write onto your canvas. First, use an OnFocusChanged listener to set your edittext text to a string, then write it onto your canvas in the Ondraw(c) call for the canvas. Before you do, though you need a string to write to (etstring) from your edittext, and you need to declare a paint object.

```
 Paint paint= new Paint();
 paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF); //sets typface
 int textx = screenwidth/2;  //use screenwidth/2 to center the text
 c.drawText(etstring, textx, 85, paint); //85 is the height
```